# Generate custom dynamic URL in Contact Form 7 body

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I need to add in the contact form body a custom filter. I was reading through the custom code to be written in `functions.php` but I wasn’t clear on how to use it for my case.

I have the following situation. I have `yith` plugin which has this code

```
<?php echo apply_filters( 'yith_wcwl_email_share_body', urlencode( $share_link_url ) ) ?>
```

This code generates a specific `URL` that can be shared in social networks and by email. I want to send this `URL` not through the share function, but as a part of the `Contact Form 7`.

Can anyone help me implement this code so the dynamically generated `url` from this code will be sent by email when `Contact form 7` is compiled and sent?